# Does the AutocompleteFragment provided by the Places API library has a built-in limitation of displaying fixed number of results?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am currently using the Place API library to search for nearby shores based on the user's current location. However, I have encountered a limitation with the AutocompleteFragment provided by the Places API library, which only displays a maximum of 5 results in the drop-down list. I need to display more than 5 results.

I have implemented a customized search interface using an EditText field and a RecyclerView to show the search results, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution available to achieve this requirement. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes, there's currently not a way to include more than 5 results in the drop down. The reason would be for UI/UX purposes. And also because the purpose of autocomplete is to show place predictions in response to user search queries. With that said, what would be the reason why you would like to have more than 5 though?

Comment: Thank you, @Yrll, but why does the Google Maps application search bar return more than 5 results in the dropdown list?!

Comment: Do you mean the Google Maps App itself right?

Comment: Yes of course !

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer is, Yes

We should also set our expectation that the [Google Maps App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1) and the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps) are different platforms so there could be difference in features.

This means that not because the Google Maps App is able to return more than 5 result, it should too in the API.

A [Public Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821928#comment4) was closed as infeasible due to the following reasons as mentioned there:

> **Status: Won't Fix (Infeasible)** - "*Place Autocomplete provides suggestions to show beneath an input field; these are meant to suggest only a few highly likely places, and there is typically limited screen space."*

We should also consider two main things:

- As mentioned in the comment above, UI/UX must be very important here. Not having limits in how many predictions to show could create issues to different types of screens. For example, if the API is being used in cars or small screen devices.
- Developers have been using this same 5 results feature for many years already and changing the number of predictions being shown could cause some problems in their apps also.

I hope these information helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is a bit iffy - an API should not be concerned with the UI. However I get the point with the backwards compatibility, but you could easily mitigate that by adding an additional parameter to request which sets an explicit result cap and set it to a default value of 5. But this is just an opinion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).